# Position div in the middle of the screen w/jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to add an overlay box in the middle of the screen. I must remain there until I remove it. I should remain in the middle even when the page is scrolled. My guess I need a relative positioning but how do I get the margins etc. Do I need to use jQuery to calculate it?

```
$(".myBox").css("margin-top", $(document).height()/2 - $(".myBox").height()/2);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have there?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a width and height specified for your div then you can use (CSS code):

```
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: auto;
```

or if you want to do this in jQuery:

```
$(".myBox").css("margin-top", "auto");
$(".myBox").css("margin-left", "auto");
```

This should be supported by IE as well as Firefox, Opera, Safari etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `position:fixed` (not supported by IE<7). https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position for meeting this requirement: "It should remain in the middle even when the page is scrolled."

```
$(".myBox").css("top", $(document).height()/2 - $(".myBox").height()/2);
$(".myBox").css("position", "fixed");
```